# how to change the intensity of two lights at the same time?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

how to change the intensity of several lights at the same time keeping the aspect ratio in a static scene? for example: change the intensity of several area lights directly on the intensity button of any one of the lights and all the others in the group also undergo change keeping the proportion established previously?

Comment: Use drivers and encode ratio in drivers

Comment: do you have a tutorial? I already tried to configure the driver , but I can not get results ?

Comment: Hover over source intensity. right click copy  as new driver. hover over dest. right click paste drive. right click edit driver. switch to script expression type x * var in expression. use what you want for c

Comment: @MrBill that was a bit cryptic, but if you can simplify it I will upvote it as an answer. I might also add that you can use a single custom property to drive all the lights, which means that it will have as zero to one value that will be easy to multiply by and set things up.

Comment: @thelabcat is that ok?

Answer (score 4):

To use one property to drive another you create a driver from the first property. then copy the driver to the second property. then edit the driver to do what you want.

You create a driver by hovering over the property input, right click, and select copy as driver

You copy it by hovering over the second property input, right click, and select paste driver.

You edit the driver by hovering over the second property, right click and select edit driver.

You want to do this with the lights intensity.

The new driver is set to average value but you want to multiply intensity. change ave value to scripted expression in driver editor. new input will show up. type x * var in field. but for x use number you want to multiply by.

You can copy the driver to each light and replace x by a different value to set different proportions.

If you want all lights using same intensity you can make a new custom property and make the driver from it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion
but I can't set the aspect ratio.
is there a tutorial with images about this configuration?

Comment: another question: how do I configure the intensity to be changed from any light in the group while maintaining the proportion?

Comment: actually I wanted to adjust the intensity of several lights and then with a button change the intensity of all the lights keeping the proportion. it's possible ?

Comment: I think you are wrong.
according to the video the settings are different from the ones you mentioned. in any case thanks. follow video with tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8ER1wOOg1Y